# Changing languages while running iPad app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Is there a way to apply the selected language in your iPad app?
Setting the langauge is not the problem, but applying it to the screens is difficult.
The project I've made is a master/detail storyboard app, so on both master and detail the choosen language should be applied. The languages are set via AppleLanguages.

Answer (score 0):

===================EDIT, infos from APPLE============================================

In general, you should not change the iOS system language (via use of the AppleLanguages pref key) from within your application. This goes against the basic iOS user model for switching languages in the Settings app, and also uses a preference key that is not documented, meaning that at some point in the future, the key name could change, which would break your application.

If you want to switch languages in your application, you can do so via manually loading resource files in your bundle. You can use NSBundle:pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:forLocalization: for this purpose, but keep in mind that your application would be responsible for all loading of localized data.

Regarding the exit(0) question, Apple DTS cannot comment on the app approval process. You should contact appreview@apple.com to get an answer for this question.

http://aggressive-mediocrity.blogspot.in/2010/03/custom-localization-system-for-your.html

This link may help you i guess. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the link, it really helped me out!